# copy exact excel cell format and text font to itextpdf

Tags: java, apache-poi, itext

I am using apache-poi and itext in java to read a xlsx file and convert it into a pdf in java.
I am reading an Excel sheet (xlsx) using xssfsheet which i want to write to a pdf. How can I copy the exact format of the text and the cell(cell width etc) to the PdfPCell to write in my pdf?

```
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = worksheet.iterator();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable();      
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
Row row = rowIterator.next();
Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
     Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
     //Manipulate cell data and copy to PdfPCell here
     }
}
```

I am reading my excel file something like this. Please help !
Want to copy the text font and format as well as the cell width and alignment from the excel sheet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solved this? I have exact same problem.